# Solution with map gave AC and Solution with unordered_map gave WA. why?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, unordered-map, keymaps

I am looking for any difference between `map` and `unordere_map` which is now known by most of people.

The problem : [Problem Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers)

the solution with map: [Accepted Solution](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers/submissions/code/41493679)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    map<int,int> mp;
    map<int,int> ::iterator it;
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int X;
        cin >> X;
        mp[X]++;
    }    
    for(it=mp.begin();it!=mp.end();++it){
        int X = it->first;   
        //cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
        ans = max(ans,mp[(X-1)]+mp[(X)]);
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

The solution with `unordered_map`: [WA Solution](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers/submissions/code/41493660)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    unordered_map<int,int> ::iterator it;
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int X;
        cin >> X;
        mp[X]++;
    }     
    for(it=mp.begin();it!=mp.end();++it){
        int X = it->first;   
        //cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
        ans = max(ans,mp[(X-1)]+mp[(X)]);
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl; 
    return 0;
}


Input :
       98
       7 12 13 19 17 7 3 18 9 18 13 12 3 13 7 9 18 9 18 9 13 18 13 13 18 18 17 17 13 3 12 13 19 17 19 12 18 13 7 3 3 12 7 13 7 3 17 9 13 13 13 12 18 18 9 7 19 17 13 18 19 9 18 18 18 19 17 7 12 3 13 19 12 3 9 17 13 19 12 18 13 18 18 18 17 13 3 18 19 7 12 9 18 3 13 13 9 7
Output : 10
Expected Output : 30
```

As far as I know that only difference with `map` and `unordered_map` is that map contain key in sorted fashion while `unordered_map` not.

Comment: As part of a [MCVE], you need to provide the inputs, as well as expected and observed outputs in the body of the question. Please edit them in, linking to outside sites is asking us to do more work, and increases the risk of link rot rendering your question unintelligible to future readers.

Comment: I provided input and expected output too. I put the link for more clarification. Anyway question has sufficient information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mp[(X-1)]` may need to insert a new element into the map (if the key `X-1` wasn't present already). With `std::map`, inserting a new element doesn't invalidate any existing iterators. With `std::unordered_map`, it may (if insertion happens to trigger rehashing). When it does, `it` becomes invalid and the subsequent `++it` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks
Now  it work as

          //simple check, before accessing
           if( mp.find(X-1)!=mp.end()){
                     ans = max(ans,mp[(X-1)]+mp[(X)]);
            }